# Using MAXIFS with messy workbook

Tags: excel, vba

This is the last step in a long via script.  I'm trying to fill in the maximum values in column H using criteria from column C and values from E.  The problem is that the last row in column E can vary from 50 to, well, whatever Excel can handle (approx. max Excel rows/50).  Any tips?  Thanks. (Yes, I know the code is sloppy.  This was created from an earlier version that was much less efficient.)

```
  sFile = ThisWorkbook.Name
  sFileName = sPathName & sFile
  Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(sFileName)
  Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(sFileName)
  Set wsTarget = Worksheets("Priority Values calculated")
  wsTarget.Range("G2").Copy
  wsTarget.Range("G2").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
  wsTarget.Range("H1") = "Seats In Each State"
  
  With wbTarget
  
    wsTarget.Range("H2") = 1
    wsTarget.Range("H2") = MAXIFS($E$2:$E$&lLastRow,!$C$2:$C$&lLastRow, C2)
    
  End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Writing a Formula to a Dynamic Single-Column Range

```vb
sFileName = sPathName & ThisWorkbook.Name
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(sFileName)
Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets("Priority Values calculated")

With wsTarget
    .Range("G2").Value = .Range("G2").Value ' copy/paste values
    .Range("H1").Value = "Seats In Each State"
    '.Range("H2").Value = 1 ' ???
    .Range("H2:H" & lLastRow).Formula _
        = "=MAXIFS($E$2:$E$" & lLastRow & ",$C$2:$C$" & lLastRow & ",C2)"
End With
```